# Javascript Socket.IO - Socket empty when passing to other object

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, undefined

I'm trying to give the socket object to my 'ConnectionHandler' class, but when using this socket object it gives this error: 'cannot read property socket of undefined socket.io'.

Server class:

```js
Server.prototype.handleConnections = function ()
{
 this.queueTime = 15; // Queue time in seconds

 var that = this; // Create a global variable of the server object

 // On incoming connection
 this.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connection incoming...'); // Log a message to the server console

  // When a client tries to join the queue
  socket.on('client_join_queue', function (username) {
   // Check if the username is valid
   if (! (username.length < 3)) {
    var newPlayer = new player(username);
    var connectionHandler = new connectionHandling(socket, that, newPlayer);
    that.connections.push(connectionHandler);
   }
  });
 });
}
```

ConnectionHandler class:

```js
'use strict';

var ConnectionHandler = function (_socket, _server, _player)
{
 this.socket = _socket;
 this.server = _server;
 this.player = _player;

 this.server.queueHandler.addPlayer(this.player);

 this.server.connections[0].socket.emit('player_joined_queue', this.player, this.server.queueHandler.getQueue().length);

 var that = this;
 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  console.log("user disconnected");
  console.log("queue:", that.server.queueHandler.getQueue());
 });
}

module.exports.ConnectionHandler = ConnectionHandler;
```

I've absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: socket.emit from client side and socket.on from server side name should be same.

Comment: I'm not getting what you're trying to say. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

What fljs was saying, you are emitting an event called 'player_joined_queue'.
But you are listening for the event 'client_join_queue'. You need to listen for the event with the same name you are emitting. So you would need to change one or the other. for example,

```
socket.on('player_joined_queue', function (username) {
...
```